# dynamic div's with dynamic height using css

Tags: css

How to assign height to div's inside parent div so that they stretch to full height?

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="c1">abc</div>  
<div class="c2">abc</div>// conditionally present
<div class="c3">abc</div>// conditionally present
<div class="c4">abc</div>
</div>
```

when c2,c3 are present all child div must have some height set and when c2,c3 not present I want c4 to take up rest of the space.

Comment: It sounds like you're assuming the parent has some kind of height set (such as `100vh`). Otherwise it will only be as tall as its content. If the parent does have a height set, this layout is easy to do with Flexbox or Grid.

Comment: parent height is set to 100%, i.e. visible in a panel without having scroll.

Comment: I am not clear what you mean by ‘rest of the space’. When the two middle divs disappear, how high should the first child div be?

Answer (score 1):

You could use flexbox to set the last element to grow when the last element, you need the parent element to have a set height to make it work such as `100vh`.

you can then toggle the style of the last element to be `flex: 1`.

```js
const c2 = document.getElementsByClassName("c2");
const c3 = document.getElementsByClassName("c3");
const c4 = document.getElementsByClassName("c4");

const toggleItems = () => {
  c2[0].style.display = c2[0].style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
  c3[0].style.display = c3[0].style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
  c4[0].style.flex = c4[0].style.flex === '1 1 0%' ? '0 0 0' : '1 1 0%';
}
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

div:not(.parent) {
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.c1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.c2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.c3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.c4 {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleItems()">remove items</button>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="c1">abc</div>
  <div class="c2">abc</div>
  <div class="c3">abc</div>
  <div class="c4">abc</div>
</div>
```